# React CSS is duplicated

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I have a problem where all of the CSS (style tags) output in my React app are duplicated.
The picture below shows an example of the duplication. I have included a copy of my `webpack.config.js` file here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mdv5Z9bB9v/. I have no idea what's causing this and would love some suggestions for ways to debug this.

Please let me know if any other info is needed!

[image]

Comment: Can you show the js file for the element this css applies to?

Comment: 100% of the site's CSS is duplicated, but here is one of the components (the only place which uses the h2.welcome that you see above): https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4x757by67H/

Comment: Yes, I am sure that I am not importing the file twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was importing the `bundle.js` file in the HTML, although it is added automatically by the webpack, therefore all of the components were being imported twice and hence the CSS was duplicated.

This solution came from here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader/issues/143